# Int variable not changing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to increment my int variable `i` when a button is pressed. However, it's not working.

```
var i:int = 0;

DB_47_ENTER_ROOM105.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, DB_47_ENTER_ROOM105_Action);

function DB_47_ENTER_ROOM105_Action(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(i);
    if (i == 0) {
        gotoAndStop(49);
        i = 1;
    }

    if (i == 1) {
        gotoAndStop(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What isn't working?  What is happening, and what do you expect to happen?   There is no increment in your code, just `i` starting out as `0`, then forever being `1` after the first click.

Comment: This code is in a  frame and after you click goes directly to another frame where i doesn't exist in anymore.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Whoops, I mean. `i` isn't staying `1` but instead turns back to `0`. Try running the code because for some reason `i` always goes back to `0`.

Comment: Does the frame this code run on get repeated? That's likely your problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no other code elsewhere that manipulates the value of `i`, then your issue is likely that the frame to which this code belongs, is getting repeated (eg the timeline loops or you go back to this frame.   Whenever this frame runs, your `i` var will get recreated because of:

```
var i:int = 0;  //if i already exists, this will just set it to 0.
```

What you can do, is not assign the value:

```
var i:int;  //don't assign a value on the var declaration
```

Since the default value for an int is `0`, not further changes should be needed.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem. :D